# How to disable a button after i click it in discord nextcord

Tags: python, nextcord

I want to make the button grey and unclickable.

For example:

**Dank memer example**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the callback for your button, you can use

```
button.disabled = True
```

which will disable your button for all users.

[Here's a good example of how to use it](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/blob/master/examples/views/counter.py)

[Reference](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.ui.Button.disabled)